# How can i write a script that creates a .cpp file with all the header stuff already in it?

Tags: c++, bash

I want to write a bash script that will take an input name and create a new .cpp file that has all of the headers in it already.

tldr; I want a script that makes a .cpp file with this in it already

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a script?  Just create a file.  Then make a copy and rename it as many times as you need.

Comment: This is called a template. If you want a bash function to copy a template to a new name, that should be easy to implement. I'm not sure why you'd stamp out a `main` function each time. Those are usually defined once and once only. Additionally, please **stop** `using namespace std` and embrace the `std::` prefix. It helps avoid collisions with your own code and classes.

Comment: Most decent text editors will allow you to create a template that should be used anytime a new file ending with `.cpp` is created.

Comment: @tadman, i was using this at the beginning of my cs 102 course in college and this is the way we are told to code in c++ :/

Comment: It's usually the case that university is a good place to learn theory, but a terrible place to learn best practices. Many professors have highly quirky interpretations of how to write C++. The good news is there's many [books that help rectify this](https://www.aristeia.com/books.html) if you want to learn how to write *real* C++ code, and not just C++ code for your professor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTENT="#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {

}"

echo "$CONTENT" > $1
```

Run the script using `./script.sh <target>`, e.g: `./script.sh example.cpp`